# XPath extract value within attribute

Tags: xpath, attributes, extract

This is my HTML code so far:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td nowrap="x">Citation(s)</td>
    <td>
        <span class="pubmed_id" id="26472973">
            <a href="/pubmed/26472973">26472973</a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to extract the number `26472973`, which is a value that changes for each entry in the database.

Comment: You need to tell us what DOESN'T change for each entry; navigating to a node in the tree requires knowledge of what fixed landmarks can be used for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if you want to get either the value from the attribute `@id` or the following `a` element.
So, for the attribute value, try this XPath:

```
//tr[@valign='top']/td/span[@class='pubmed_id']/@id
```

Or, for the element's `a` value use this XPath:

```
//tr[@valign='top']/td/span[@class='pubmed_id']/a/text()
```

In both case the result is `26472973`.

Comment: The first script selected one element but it doesn't extract it.  The second didn't select anything.

Comment: I tested both expressions and they both succeeded. If they didn't work for you, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @kxb35 , Most likely that value or webElement that you're trying to handle generated dynamically by JavaScript, so you cannot get it by parsing page source... or you're using inappropriate method for extracting the value

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want the 'citations', here another try:

```
//tr/td[text()='Citation(s)']/following-sibling::td/span/@id
```